# SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

Tags: sql-server, ssas, visual-studio-2012, tabular-model

I use `SQL Server 2012` and `SSAS Tabular Mode` (My Instance Name Is MSSQLSERVER2012T)

Then I download `AdventureWorks Tabular Model SQL Server 2012` From [This link](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330)

I open it with `Visual Studio 2010` and configure my `Instance Name` like this picture :

[image]

[image]

When I deploy my project I have This picture :

[image]

But after one minute I get this error :

[image]

And when I click on `Details Of Error` I get this message :

[image]

```
OLE DB or ODBC error: Login timeout expired; HYT00; 
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while 
establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. 
Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow 
remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.; 08001; 
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. ; 08001.

A connection could not be made to the data source with 
the DataSourceID of 'a16b8d9d-3811-4be1-91e7-a9d0a2df4d38', 
Name of 'SqlServer localhost'.
```

[image]

And

[image]

But it not work for me???

In my `SSAS` one Database was created like this picture :

[image]

Comment: 1) The error message is talking about Named Pipes, not TCP, and 2) Why are you fiddling with your SQL Server Express's network settings when elsewhere you seem to be talking to the 2012 Developer Edition?

Comment: Moreover, the error indicates it attempted to connect to LOCALHOST, not a named instance... (local)\mssqlserver2012t  .. as described in your first screenshot

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : How I Can fix my problem? How I can fix Named Pipes?! what is my problem?

Comment: @drewlander : After fix my instance name(.\MSSQLServer2012T) , one database was created in my SSAS (see last pic.)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Generally, the "Named Pipes" reference in this error is a red herring.  Named Pipes is just the last of the three protocols (Memory, TCP, Named Pipes) that is checked for a match between client and server, so it is always the protocol that is used in the error message.  If the OP wants the SQL Server to support TCP (and this is what MS recommends), then they likely need to change the *client* configuration settings also (the client and server settings are separate, even on the same box).  Also, there are 32bit and 64bit versions of each.

Comment: I think you should assign TCP Port number as 1433 in TCP/IP's each and every property. It should work

Comment: If you look at he question, the "All IPs" section shows Port 1433.  This means there is no need to change it for all the other interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your named Pipes connections are disabled, try fixing this[image: In he SQL Server Configuration Manager]

Comment: Why do I have the feeling that @Damien is right and you both are looking at the wrong instance? Shouldn't that 2012 named instance be used in this process?

Comment: I think you are correct. Port number 1433 is also unusual for a named instance.